# Perftools Error: Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread for Ruby 1.9.3-p194

Tags: ruby

I'm getting this error when I try doing rake db:migrate. Quite frustrating. I have installed perftools 2.0, but doesn't seem to help.

This is the full trace:

```
dn51vdfn:rails jasonvdm$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/perftools.rb-0.5.6/lib/perftools.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread
Referenced from: /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/perftools.rb-0.5.6/lib/perftools.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/perftools.rb-0.5.6/lib/perftools.bundle - /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/perftools.rb-0.5.6/lib/perftools.bundle
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/rack-perftools_profiler-0.5.0/lib/rack/perftools_profiler/profiler.rb:43:in `initialize'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/rack-perftools_profiler-0.5.0/lib/rack/perftools_profiler/profiler_middleware.rb:20:in `new'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/rack-perftools_profiler-0.5.0/lib/rack/perftools_profiler/profiler_middleware.rb:20:in `initialize'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/rack-perftools_profiler-0.5.0/lib/rack/perftools_profiler.rb:20:in `new'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/rack-perftools_profiler-0.5.0/lib/rack/perftools_profiler.rb:20:in `new'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `block in build'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `each'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `inject'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `build'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:447:in `app'
/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Help? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p194

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/bhb/rack-perftools_profiler/issues/16

Comment: Me too, but the fixes mentioned don't help. They seem meant for p0

Comment: Still cant fix it, help anyone?

Comment: You said you installed perftools 2.0. Why does the error message still reference `perftools.rb-0.5.6`? Try and clean up your gems a bit?

Comment: Good catch. Should I uninstall perftools first and then reinstall?

Comment: /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find perftools.rb-0.5.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: I get that error now... hrm. Something seems dependent on 0.5.6

Comment: Did you remove your `Gemfile.lock`? If not then you should..

Comment: Where would I find that? I have not removed it

Comment: In your rails project root. Not sure if that is the problem though. Just guessing.

Comment: That did help, it installed a lot more. I now get this error though:

Comment: Resolved collector.newrelic.com to 204.93.223.153
rake aborted!
undefined method `confirm_within=' for Devise:Module

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: still having problems... hmm, help?

Comment: This is a new issue..make a new question and post the trace. Also post the contents of your Gemfile in the new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143505/error-with-rake-dbmigrate-undefined-method-confirm-within-for-devisemodule

Comment: Looks like someone helped you there already :) Good luck..