# Error with Rake DB:Migrate undefined method `confirm_within=' for Devise:Module

Tags: ruby, devise

I'm getting this error when I try run DB:Rake  :

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time) 
** Execute environment
Resolved collector.newrelic.com to 204.93.223.153
 rake aborted!
 undefined method `confirm_within=' for Devise:Module
 /Users/jasonvdm/development/rails/config/initializers/devise.rb:66:in `block in <top   (required)>'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:247:in    `setup'
 /Users/jasonvdm/development/rails/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 /Users/jasonvdm/development/rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
 /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@wheelz/gems/activesupport- 3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
```

Not sure why i'm getting these errors at all.

This is what it is my gemfile, leaving out some of the end portions that are private.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
# gem 'sqlite3'

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
 gem 'typus', '~> 3.1.8'
 gem "ckeditor-rails", :git => "https://github.com/fesplugas/rails-ckeditor.git" # for     typus _text_with_ckeditor.html.erb
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'koala'
gem 'rc_rails'
gem 'dynamic_form' # to get back old 'error_messages_on' behavior
gem 'role_model'
gem 'renum'
gem 'geokit', "1.6.0"
gem 'rails3-settings', '~> 1.0.0', :require => 'settings', :git =>  'git://github.com/jlaxson/rails-settings'
gem 'acts_as_api'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'xml-simple', :require => 'xmlsimple'
gem 'braintree', '>= 2.15.0'
gem 'carmen'
gem 'state_machine', :git => 'git://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine.git'
```

rest is hidden due to privacy

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an error in `config/initializers/devise.rb` (line 66). Without seeing that code it seems as though you are calling a method on Devise called `confirm_within` that was renamed to `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` in Devise 2.0.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0

Comment: @JasonvanderMerwe - No. You are already running 2.0. Fix the error in `config/initializers/devise.rb`. Learn to read your error messages. It's a skill like riding a bicycle. It's very clear exactly where the error is. You'll save a lot of time and won't have to post to SO every time you get an error if you just read what it says on the screen. Look at line 66 in `devise.rb`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it, I wasn't sure what to change the method to.

Comment: Ugh, another undefined method, database_authenticatable. I'll try and figure this one out though.